# On index page i get error Breadcrumbs::getProductName() must be of the type string, null returned in readcrumbs.php:101

Tags: magento2.4, index, breadcrumbs, magento2.4.1

Ok, this is the full error actually:

```
TypeError: Return value of Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs::getProductName() must be of the type string, null returned in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/ViewModel/Product/Breadcrumbs.php:101
```

When I open index page it shows this error and long stack trace of 70 files.

I inspected the source magento files and its this function, which seams alright. So I am confused what is doing it.

```
public function getProductName(): string
    {
        return $this->catalogData->getProduct() !== null
            ? $this->catalogData->getProduct()->getName()
            : '';
    }
```

I am using latest magento 2.4.1
I tried disablin all 3-rd party modules. Changes nothing.

Comment: Looks like you have quotes in product name.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15631

Comment: Yeah, you reminded me of that bug. How did it end up in 2.4.1 . I am guessing one of my modules contains override code from earlier versions.

Comment: I resolved just resave product with a name which throw exception.

Comment: But what about mass import?

Comment: I got the same error. Did anyone solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so for anyone that has this problem. It is an open ticket.

As Anton said double quotes are causing this problem. So the solution is to **remove double quotes from title of products**.

Answer (score 1):

solution: login to admin goto catalog->product search for the product where any product has no product name and URL key.

just update the product name and URL key.

this was fixed for me.